# How to make fields position permanently on one side if other field appears on some condition in vf page?

Tags: visualforce

I have a field "Actual Delivery Date" that only appears on the vf page on some conditions, as shown in the code below! Due to this other fields appear randomly on the vf page. I want these 4 fields to permanently appear on the right side of vf page: Document Courier, Document Tracking ID, Document ETD, Document ETA. These 4 fields shouldn't depend on the appearance of the Actual delivery date field.

Here's the code

```html
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Dispatch Details">
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Loaded_from_Plant__c}"> 
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
    </apex:outputField>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!IF(Order__c.Status_for_abs__c == 'Invoicing' || Order__c.Status_for_abs__c == 'Dispatched',false,true)}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Document_tracking_ID__c}"> 
    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/></apex:outputField>
           
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Delivery_Date__c}" label="Actual Delivery Date" rendered="{!IF((Order__c.Status_for_abs__c == 'Invoicing' || Order__c.Status_for_abs__c == 'Dispatched') && Order__c.Loaded_from_Plant__c,true,false)}" ><apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/></apex:outputField>
            
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Document_ETA__c}"> 
       <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/></apex:outputField>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Carrier__c}"><apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/></apex:outputField>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Document_ETD__c}"> 
       <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/></apex:outputField>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.ETD__c}" ><apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/></apex:outputField>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Document_Courier_Name__c}"><apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/></apex:outputField>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Tracking_ID__c}" > 
       <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/></apex:outputField>
    <br/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.ETA__c}" ><apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/></apex:outputField>

</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add empty element, and render it if the Actual Delivery Date is not visible, and then the other elements will remain in the same position

Something like:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Delivery_Date__c}" label="Actual Delivery Date" rendered="{!showDeliveryDate}" ></apex:outputField>

<pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{! !showDeliveryDate}"/>
```